# WordPress: Custom Users not Appearing in Author box

Tags: php, wordpress

I've added a **custom user type** in Wordpress, the **custom post type** supports Authors(See below). The custom user type has all the privileges of an author except for 'publish posts', but is **not** on the list of possible authors to assign to the post.

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
if (!get_role('member')) {
        add_role('member', 'SFUK Member', array(
            'delete_posts' => true,
            'edit_posts' => true,
            'read' => true,
            'upload_files' => true,
            'edit_published_posts' => true,
            'delete_published_posts' => true
        ));
}
```

and here is the custom post type :

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'menu_position' => 0,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes', 'author')
);

if (!post_type_exists('ent')) {
    register_post_type('ent', $args);
    remove_post_type_support('ent', 'editor');

}
```

Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Does the user privileges work in wp-admin? the way you expect it to?... Also are you using a custom theme / widget to show the author name when published?, does it show a wrong value?, or just blank. There is alot of ways this could have been done wrong sadly =[

Comment: Also which files your code snippets comes from =P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The authors dropdown is created the following call:

```
wp_dropdown_users( array(
    'who' => 'authors',
    'name' => 'post_author_override',
    'selected' => empty($post->ID) ? $user_ID : $post->post_author,
    'include_selected' => true
) );
```

The `who` argument means that only users with at least 'author' role will be listed, and [the Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_users) says that currently it's either 'authors' or empty (meaning all users).
There is **a filter for this function** but it takes the HTML as input. You could create a new query for users and then output a new HTML dropdown. This is the first way to solve your problem.

However, this function with 'who' set to 'authors' searches for users whose level is not 0 which is quite strange since user levels have been deprecated long ago. I've found [a related bug report](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16841) on Trac recommending that you **add a 'level_1' capability** to your new role to fix this. This is not a clean solution but much easier than creating a filter and all HTML from scratch.

**EDIT**: A third and even more simple solution just came to my mind: I've created custom roles with plugins but never noticed this problem because I was always **copying capabilities from existing roles** and then modifying them. This way you won't forget any capabilities and it will also fix this bug.

Comment: Okay, I added a level_1 capability, but it didn't help. How might I copy capabilities from an existing roles. I can't think of a neat way to do it.

Comment: Make sure that you removed the previously created custom role because add_role does nothing if the role already exists (thus your 'if' isn't needed). Anyway, here's how I did it: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/creating-a-role-based-on-another?replies=2, and another example: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-a-custom-role-based-on-default-role?replies=1

Comment: Okay, sorted now. Thanks again!